# Auto Draft Specific Categories Posts after a certain number of Days

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-cron, draft

I want to put posts from two categories to automatically draft after the number of days like 90 Days from the date of Publish and I created a function with the help of some codes in other forums, but its not working.

Post type = **property**
Taxonomy = **property-ad-type**
Targeted Property Ad Type Categories with IDs = **(free-text-only-ad - ID:108)**, **(photo-ad - ID: 107)**
Targeted Number of Days = (**90Days from the date of Publish**)

I added this function

```
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'property_status_update');
//add_action('init','property_ad_status_update');

function property_status_update() {
    $the_query = get_posts( 'post_type=property' ); 
    foreach($the_query as $single_post) {
        $id=$single_post->ID;
        $post_date=get_post_modified;
        $taxonomy = 'property-ad-type';
        if($taxonomy = '108' || $taxonomy = '107'){
            $today=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-24 days'));
            if($post_date = $today){
                $update_post = array(
                   'ID'             => $id,
                   'post_status'    =>  'draft',
                   'post_type'  =>  'property' );
                wp_update_post($update_post);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two most important notes to your code. It's not working, because always will be retrieved only 5 (the default value of `'post_per_page'` parameter) recent posts. If you want to [add a task to the cron](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event), you **do not** specify the **function name** as the parameter, but the name of the **action hook**. And you attach a function to this action hook.

```
add_action( 'se354599_old_posts_to_draft', '{function-name}' );
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'se354599_old_posts_to_draft' );
```

The task should be added to the schedule only once, preferably when activating the plugin or theme. 
But you can also:

- set the option after scheduling the task ([`add_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option)), and check if it exists before you schedule the task with [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event),
- before scheduling the tasks, check whether there is already scheduled ([`wp_next_scheduled()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_next_scheduled))

Now the parameters of the [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters) function.

To update the status of the post there is no need to retrieve all the data of the post, just its ID.

```
'fields' => 'ids'
```

You want to get all posts that meet the conditions, so you need to set the `post_per_page` parameter to `-1`.
To limit results to posts published more than 90 days ago use [`'date_query'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters) parameter.
To limit results to specific custom categories use [`'tax_query'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) parameter.

Having posts IDs, all you have to do is update their status. Use [`wp_update_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) function 
or divide results array into smaller pieces (e.g. 30 items each) and update posts in batches ([`$wpdb->query(()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Running_General_Queries))

```
add_action( 'init', 'se354599_add_cronjob' );
add_action( 'se354599_old_posts_to_draft', 'se354599_update_post' );

function se354599_add_cronjob()
{
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'se354599_old_posts_to_draft' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'se354599_old_posts_to_draft');
    }
    // DISABLE
    //if ( wp_next_scheduled( 'se354599_old_posts_to_draft' ) ) {
    //    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'se354599_old_posts_to_draft' );
    //}
}

function se354599_update_post()
{
    $args = [
        'post_type'     => 'property',
        'fields'        => 'ids',
        'post_per_page' => -1,
        'date_query'    => [
            'before' => '-90 day',
        ],
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy'  => 'property-ad-type',
                'include_children' => false,
                'field'     => 'term_id',
                'terms'     => [107, 108],
                // --- or by slug: ---
                // 'field'     => 'slug',   // ‘term_id’, ‘name’, ‘slug’ or ‘term_taxonomy_id’
                // 'terms'     => ['free-text-only-ad', 'photo-ad'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $to_update = get_posts( $args );
    if ( !is_array($to_update) || empty($to_update) )
        return;

    $arg = [ 'ID' => 0, 'post_status' => 'draft' ];
    foreach ( $to_update as $pID ) 
    {
        $arg['ID'] = (int)$pID;
        wp_update_post( $arg );
    }
}
```