# get current date + 90 days and checking every day

Tags: plugins, functions, hooks, post-meta, mysql

User can submit post from frontend submission form.
Fieldname:

```
Title (entered by user)
expire_date (entered by user)
expire_date1 (invisible)
expired (invisible)
```

When user enter no value for "expire_date" then i have to enter fallback value for custom field expire_date1.
The fallback value is: current date + 90 days.

In next step: When date has been reached then change custom field "expired" from 0 to 1.

How to automate this writing and checking process?

Comment: You can do the same as in [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/354599/auto-draft-specific-categories-posts-after-a-certain-number-of-days/354864#354864) case.